# SQL SSRS 2012 Subqueries and parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, subreport

I have 2 databases on 2 servers. I have a main report generating a bunch of data, 1 field correlates to the 2nd servers db. I have a subreport that gets the parameter from the first, does it's thing and spits out results. Works fine.

The problem is this happens per row of the main report. So let's say we end up with three rows in the main report after executing. I have 3 sets of data from the subreport all nice and neat, that I can't then get a grand total on because the subreports don't talk to each other and since they are subreports I can't seem to reference it's data in the main report.

So how can I do this, either with 2 datasets in 1 report passing executed parameters into the 2nd dataset and getting results as though it were a subquery. Or, some other method I haven't figured out? Someone mentioned somewhere about using a detail row with a 2nd dataset/query but I can't seem to figure that out or if it's accurate.

To summarize, you execute the report, it gets a list of stuff grouped by date, that group has a subquery attached that uses the list to get data from 2nd server db, then grand total those rows from subquery HOW?

Any help is appreciated, maybe even using 1 query, but then I would have to link the 2 servers in SQL which I haven't done yet.

Comment: What is stopping you linking the two servers?

Comment: And do you absolutely need this to be split over two reports?  What is stopping you having everything in the one report?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't link the two servers which is *probably* the best option (Not always though; if you need a small amount of result data from very large tables this would be a bad idea), I would recommend having a dataset that contains the totals for the table in your main report, which either only returns one row so you can get the relevant total using the expression:

```
=first(Fields!Total1.Value, "TotalsDataset")
```

or you can have multiple rows that have an ID/Key column that you can link to to your groupings in your table, from which you can then use:

```
=lookup(Fields!GroupKey.Value
       ,Fields!GroupForeignKey.Value
       ,Fields!GroupTotal.Value
       ,"TotalsDataset"
       )
```